# How to enable UTF-8 in jsPDF library

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, utf-8, jspdf

I am very happy to use jsPDF library which helps me to export my HTML page as PDF file. I came across some difficulties. I downloaded the library from http://parall.ax/products/jspdf/. When I use some characters like š, ć (UTF-8), in pdf they look like error. Even if I insert via doc.text. On the library's website, when I use their examples and change text using some of these characters - it works. So it is suppose to work with UTF-8. Why it isn't working on my computer.

I provide you my code. All missing here is the lib (which can be downloaded from the website) and you will see my problem. And why the CSS is dissapeared in pdf?

**testing.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TESTING JSPDF LIB</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdffile.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Deflate/adler32cs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Blob.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script>
function redirect() {
    document.write("Hello world" + '<br />');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box" class="box-shadow">
    <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" value="LETS TRY" onClick="redirect();pdf();" /> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**pdffile.js**

```
function pdf() {
document.write('<div id="mydiv" style="background-color:#CCC; width:780px;640px;"><p>Open these letters š and c in PDF file and see error</p></div><br />');
document.write('<button id="export">OPEN IN PDF FILE</button>');

$(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(35, 25, "Text with the letter Š");
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        'body': function (element, renderer) { 
            return true;
        }
    };
    $('#export').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#mydiv').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that your html/javascript file is saved in UTF-8 encoding/format?

Comment: As per jsPDF team they wont support it yet.. You can track the status https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

Comment: Yes I am sure. It displays these characters in browser but not in pdf after. :(

Comment: you can try placing images in place of characters or may be try a fancy font. ofcourse thats a pain.

Comment: I realize that they don't support these letters in the topic you send. But how does my letters show up on their website. Please try to put Š or Č, in the title above image on their official website http://parall.ax/products/jspdf. Just change the heading.

Comment: i dont see Č coming up but i see Š. do u have link of your website?

Comment: When i type this 汉语, i dont see it. anyways u can try on the fly text to image convertor to replace certain characters

Comment: Try this http://en.pdf24.org/javascript-pdf-api.html they support UTF-8

Comment: I sent an email to the jsPDF support. They were really fast. I need to convert my HTML document to HTML5. What a stupid problem :(

Comment: But this only solve the problem with the Š. And what about Č or Ć. Is there any solution to do this that not includes fatal programming. Like simple javascript or something?

Comment: @VenkatReddy jdPDF does not support external fonts either.

Comment: @SVilcans thats a pain. Did you try this en.pdf24.org/javascript-pdf-api.html

Comment: @VenkatReddy PDF24 is server side so it's not an option for me.

Comment: imho, in 2018 jsPDF support utf-8:
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464808/6532844>

Answer (score 13):

As of 2015, jsPDF doesn't support UTF-8 properly, workaround is to use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) to render jpg or png and to add it to pdf. You can use following snippet to get an idea:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

var utf_8_string_to_render = 'any_value_you_want';

Promise.all(
[
    new Promise(function (resolve) 
    {
        var temp = document.createElement("div");
        temp.id = "temp";
        temp.style = "color: black;margin:0px;font-size:20px;";
        phrase = utf_8_string_to_render;
        temp.innerHTML= phrase;
        //need to render element, otherwise it won't be displayed
        document.body.appendChild(temp);

        html2canvas($("#temp"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

                $("#temp").remove();
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        },
        });
    })
]).then(function (ru_text) { 

    doc.addImage(ru_text[0], 'JPEG', 0,0);
    doc.text(0, 10, 'Non-utf-8-string' );

    doc.save('filename.pdf');
    });


};
```

Another libraries that do support utf-8 coding are:

- [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org), which is reported to allow you to proper place your texts with coordinates.
- [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/), which renders UTF-8 characters properly, but doesn't allow you to position text, except for styling it with margins.

Comment: "onrendered" option is deprecated, html2canvas returns a Promise with the canvas as the value instead.

Answer (score 6):

jsPDF still does not support UTF-8. Though it seems pdfmake.org supports UTF-8.
Try using [their playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) and test it with your own characters.

Comment: true. But pdfmake does not support ie.

Comment: @Saulius, it does now :)

Comment: Can you link to this information somewhere? How do you know?

Comment: @trainoasis I tested myself with Chinese characters: At http://autocosts.info/CN at the end there is a PDF report to be downloaded

Answer (score 6):

I have the answer after one day of searching throw all sites.

```
toPDF(): void {
    const AmiriRegular = 'AAEAAAASAQAABAAgRFNJR2D2zXQA.....A';

    const doc = new jsPDF({ filters: ["ASCIIHexEncode"] });

    doc.addFileToVFS("Amiri-Regular.ttf", AmiriRegular);
    doc.addFont("Amiri-Regular.ttf", "Amiri", "normal");

    doc.setFont("Amiri"); // set font
    doc.setFontSize(10);

    doc.text(10,10,'אוהב אותך'.split('').reverse().join(''));
       this.CAccounts.forEach(function (AccountsBody, i) {
      doc.text(20, 20 + (i * 10),


        "ID: " + AccountsBody.ID +
        "NAME: " + AccountsBody.NAME.split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
    doc.save('employee.pdf');

  }
```

Comment: thats nice, but what about mixed english and hebrew

Answer (score 2):

jsPDF doesn't support UTF-8 Though the following plugin do make it possible as it integrates full custom font support when you can convert your file(FONT File) to BASE64.I have converted Arial Unicode to base64 and used it though it creates some spacing and alignment issues that you need to deal with by debugging into the code.

https://github.com/sphilee/jsPDF-CustomFonts-support

Answer (score 0):

In jsPDF, The 14 standard fonts in PDF are limited to the ASCII-codepage. If you want to use UTF-8 you have to integrate a custom font, which provides the needed glyphs. jsPDF supports .ttf-files. So if you want to have for example Chinese text in your pdf, your font has to have the necessary Chinese glyphs. So, check if your font supports the wanted glyphs or else it will show garbled characters instead of the right text.

To add the font to jsPDF use our fontconverter in /fontconverter/fontconverter.html. The fontconverter will create a js-file with the content of the provided ttf-file as base64 encoded string and additional code for jsPDF. You just have to add this generated js-File to your project. You are then ready to go to use setFont-method in your code and write your UTF-8 encoded text.

Alternatively you can just load the content of the *.ttf file as a binary string using fetch or XMLHttpRequest and add the font to the PDF file:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

const myFont = ... // load the *.ttf font file as binary string

// add the font to jsPDF
doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
doc.setFont("MyFont");
```