# jsPDF library cannot insert utf8 letters into pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, utf-8, jspdf

I'm struggling without success to use **jspdf library** in order to export html page as pdf file. There is one similar question here but bad answers. The problem is in UTF-8 characters, even I made all my documents utf8. What should I do to make this library (parall.ax/products/jspdf) insert letters such as š,č,ć into pdf?

Here is the link where you can try this problem (http://balkanex.info/test/start.html), or just have a look on my code below and then go to the link. I must say that I am making local app so I cannot user servers advantages.

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="runner.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Deflate/adler32cs.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Blob.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js">    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="PROCEED TO THE NEX PAGE" onClick="run();pdf();">
  </body>
</html>
```

**runner.js**

```
function run() {
    document.write('<div id="id1"><input type="text" id="name" value="Čimoki Šitano"></div><br/>');
    document.write('<div id="id3">This is the ordinary txt with č and š and ć</div><br/>');
    document.write('<button id="pdf">Export in pdf file</button></div>');
}
```

**script.js**

```
function pdf() {
$(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(35, 25, "Here are the letters š and č and ć and ž");
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        'body': function (element, renderer) { 
            return true;
        }};
    $('#pdf').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#id3').html(), 15, 35, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample.pdf');
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library doesn't support some of these letters. And the developers told that it will be accessible soon.

But, if you want to use these letters, you can make images that will replace some of the problematic letters.

For example, make the image of the letter Č and then, in the specific field you can change the letter with this image. It is quite a work. Therefore, I suggest you to change the library.

Comment: Didn't one of the developers say "it's unlikely to happen". What alternative libraries for off-line generation exists?

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the **latest version (v1.4.0) of jsPDF**. They just started to **support unicode**,  https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v.1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF does not support anything outside the ASCII range. See https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

Comment: Though, the best idea I came up with is to render characters with html2canvas and insert them as images, as I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895120/1093289).