# Add FontAwesome Icon in jsPdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, font-awesome, jspdf

I am using `jspdf.debug.js` latest version.
`FontAwesome` icons used in a web page are not rendering in `pdf`.
I added a `FontAwesome` user icon in the page.Refer to the image.(Left one is `HTML` and `pdf` output is on right)
Below is my code snippet.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.addFont('FontAwesome', 'FontAwesome', 'normal');
pdf.setFont('FontAwesome');
pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;
html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function(pdf){
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I did in this way and all works with font Awesome 5...

1. Following [this article](https://www.devlinpeck.com/tutorials/jspdf-custom-font) i uploaded the fa-solid-900-normal.ttf at https://peckconsulting.s3.amazonaws.com/fontconverter/fontconverter.html
2. I got the js file and import it.
3. In Angular i did in this way

   ```
    constructor() {
    var callAddFont = function () {
        this.addFileToVFS('fa-solid-900-normal.ttf', jsPDFfonts.fontawesome5_fa_solid_900);
        this.addFont('fa-solid-900-normal.ttf', 'fa-solid-900', 'normal');
    };
    jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
   ```

   }

where `jsPDFfonts.fontawesome5_fa_solid_900` is the content of the file

4. Then during the print process for printing an icon i did in this way

   ```
        pdf.setFont('fa-solid-900', 'normal');
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.text('\uf6f0', 15, 15*index);
   ```

i printed directly the unicode of the icon

Answer (score 2):

jspdf does not support special symbols. Here is the [gitHub issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12).
See info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895120/7751910).

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question directly, but it's a nice workaround if you use the `pdf.html()` ([docs](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html)) method. An added bonus with this approach is you don't have to bloat your PDF size with a ton of icons.

You can render the material icon (or any other icon) as in image instead, and it will render correctly in the PDF when generated via `pdf.html()`.

Below is a simple example:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d');
if (ctx) {
  ctx.font = '24px "Material Icons"';
  ctx.fillText('visibility', 0, 24);
}
const img = new Image();
img.src = canvas?.toDataURL();
const div = document.getElementById('target');
div?.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

The result in my html:

[image: icon image rendered in html]

The result in my generated PDF:

[image: icon image rendered in PDF]

I'm in Angular, so I created a directive that makes the process very simple.

```js
import {
  Directive,
  AfterViewInit,
  Renderer2,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[toImage]',
})
export class ToImageDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() size = 24;

  constructor(
    private _el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    private _renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const canvas = this._renderer.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.size;
    canvas.height = this.size;
    this._el.nativeElement.style.display = 'inline-block';
    this._el.nativeElement.style.width = `${this.size}px`;
    this._el.nativeElement.style.height = `${this.size}px`;
    const ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d');

    if (ctx) {
      ctx.font = `${this.size}px "Material Icons"`;
      ctx.fillText(this.icon, 0, this.size);
    }

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas?.toDataURL();

    this._renderer.appendChild(this._el.nativeElement, img);
  }
}
```

Remember to import in your module / standalone component, then use it like so:

```html
<span [icon]="'visibility'" toImage></span>
```

Comment: Didn't work with material icons for me, so needed this solution. But it is a fair point.