# How use UTF-8 to jsPDF - autotable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

How can I add UTF8 to my code? I need to do this because `Č`, `ř`, `č`, `ě` etc. is not working.

```js
const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, size);
const headersZvirata = [
  [
    'Číslo', 
    'Pohlaví', 
    'Narozen', 
    'Plemeno', 
    'Otec', 
    'Matka', 
    'Chovatel',
    'Poč-Kg', 
    'Poč-Kč', 
    'Krmné dny', 
    'Při-Kg', 
    'Pří-Kč', 
    'Aktuálně Kg', 
    'Aktuálně Kč', 
    'Důvod Úhynu'
  ]
];
const dataZvirata = ([....]);

doc.autoTable({
  headStyles: {
    fontSize: 10
  },
  bodyStyles: {
    fontSize: 8,
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  },
  head: headersZvirata,
  body: dataZvirata
});
```

Comment: Unless jsPDF has been updated recently, it seems you may be out of luck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895120/519413. I'd suggest you use a better library.