# Convert HTML div to pdf by JS

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want the client to download the desired #por div in PDF format by clicking the #btn button. My site is WordPress site.

I use jsPDF and it worked. But my problem is that jsPDF does not support utf-8.(I use Persian language in #por div)

What should I do? please guide me. Thankful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="por1" id="por">...</div>
<button class="btn btn-info"  id="btn"  onclick="pdf()" target="_blank" >Download PDF</button>


<script>
function pdf()
    {
    var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementById('por').innerHTML;
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.save("dataurlnewwindow");
    }
    
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable UTF-8 in jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923488/how-to-enable-utf-8-in-jspdf-library)

Answer (score 1):

Man, I'd like to help you, but unfortunately, I don't know the clue :( Sorry, but I've got this question on this website where a guy explained everything you need to know :) I hope it was useful enough!

[Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)