# UTF-8 or "İ" character not showing or notrendering

Tags: javascript, jspdf

"İ" not showing.

**Image:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
doc.addFileToVFS("Korolev", font);
doc.addFont("Korolev", "Korolev", "normal");
doc.setFont("Korolev");
doc.text(0, 15 ,"Üsküdar Üniversitesi, İSTANBUL");
```

Comment: doc.setEncoding is not a function @Jackkobec

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct way to set encoding. Only workaround with fonts. Put in google: "jspdf set UTF-8 encoding". There is a lot of answers includes this site

Comment: I searched a lot. There were no results. @Jackkobec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable UTF-8 in jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923488/how-to-enable-utf-8-in-jspdf-library)

Comment: Apparently jsPDF doesn't support UTF-8. Use a different library or try one of the workarounds from the answers on the duplicate question.

Comment: I've now switched to pdfmake. Thanks everyone.